# Disable action keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, opensuse, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm running openSUSE on HP Pavilion dm4.
I have a bunch of action keys (volume up/down, brightness, wifi etc.) on my function keys. For using standard <kbd>Fx</kbd> keys I have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

The problem is that I more often use <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> than those actions.

How can I accomplish reverse this functionality? Holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> key for triggering actions — and have normal functionality of function keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reboot, spam ESC key to enter BIOS, disable "Action Keys Mode" in the "System Configuration" section.  Don't forget to save your settings!

Comment: Thanks! It works. It makes sense to have that option in bios...